# How do I send data from selectedrow to next viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collectionview with cells containing username and image retrieved from parse. I have a view controller with a blank image and blank label, when the cell is clicked I want the user label and image from the collectionview to be placed into the blank image and label on the view controller. I know I have to use `prepareForSegue`, but I am not sure what to do after.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: friendcellView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! friendcellView



    cell.friendname.text = arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.friendpic.image =  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.row]
    //cell.friendpic.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfFriendsTest[indexPath.row])
    cell.friendpic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.friendpic.frame.size.width/2;
    cell.friendpic.clipsToBounds = true


    return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    print(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row])
}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){

    }
}



class FriendProfile: UIViewController {
var friendname = UILabel()
var friendimage = UIImageView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    friendname = UILabel()
    friendname = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,60))
    friendname.frame.origin.y = userpic.frame.size.height + 10.0
    friendname.frame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width - userpicname.frame.size.width) / 2.0
    friendname.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    friendname.text = "Username"
    friendname.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 60)
    friendname.textColor = UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")
    self.view.addSubview(friendname)


    friendimage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "default.png")!)
    friendimage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)
    friendimage.frame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width - friendimage.frame.size.width)/2.0
    friendimage.frame.origin.y = (self.view.bounds.size.height - 60)
    self.view.addSubview(friendimage)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

This is the code for the scrollview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let FriendProfileView: FriendProfile = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FriendsProfile") as! FriendProfile
    let FriendMusicView: FriendsMusic = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FriendMusic") as! FriendsMusic



    self.addChildViewController(FriendProfileView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(FriendProfileView.view)
    FriendProfileView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(FriendMusicView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(FriendMusicView.view)
    FriendMusicView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)



    var FriendMusicFrame: CGRect = FriendProfileView.view.frame
    FriendMusicFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
    FriendMusicView.view.frame = FriendMusicFrame



    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height*2)



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

The information is contained in sender:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){
        (segue.destinationViewController as! MyViewController).friendimage.image = (sender as! FriendcellView).friendpic.image
        (segue.destinationViewController as! MyViewController).friendname.text = (sender as! FriendcellView).friendName.text
    }
}
```

Substituting MyViewController for your real class and the property names as accurate.

This is dependant upon sender actually being your Cell Class, because it sends the segue.

Comment: How will it know which image and label to send?

Comment: because it's being taken from the exact cell that you clicked

Comment: Any property on your cell can now be used. the sender is the one cell you clicked

Comment: On the MyViewController how do I set up the UILabel and image since there are already values? I will update my code

Comment: Yes that does, but I am still confused on how to display it onto the view. I understand how to send the values to the viewcontroller, but how would I display those values. My attempt is above which I know is not correct

Comment: It's because the view isn't loaded. You must store the properties first

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why it is crashing first. It's either that the view controller is inside a navigation controller? OR it could be that it's not ready to have the objects yet, but since your properties are constructed in field initialisers, that may not be so. Are you using a navigation on the segue?

Comment: No I am not using a navigation controller. I tried doing this, but it is still crashing http://puu.sh/kZ8kY/7ebe16cea0.png

Comment: What is FriendProfilePages?

Comment: That is just a ScrollView and I placed two viewcontrollers in it. I have been using it throughout my project, so it does work.

Comment: So you need to send the information (image,label) to the view INSIDE the scrollview? (that is, FriendProfile is inside FriendProfilePages)?

Comment: yes, FriendProfile is indeed inside of FriendProfilePages

Comment: Do you need to apply all the properties for all labels and images of each FriendProfile or just the selected one?

Comment: Just the selected one

Comment: You need to have link to FriendProfile from FriendProfilePages, because FriendProfilePages is the _ACTUAL_ view controller. Then you can use the code selected

Comment: Where do you create it? How many FriendProfile are there? I would suggest an array. or IBOutletCollection

Comment: I updated my code, there is only one FriendProfile page, but with a blank image and label, thats why i want to prepareforsegue and populate the image and label with the one selected.

Comment: ok step 1/3: please first add a label and an image property on your scrollview. can you do that? UIImage and String

Comment: Yes, but the scroll view has two pages on it, and if I place it on the scroll view, the image and string will appear on both pages right?

Comment: no. you are thinking of UIImageView and UILabel. those are the VIEWS. You need to create a property like var label: String? and var image: UIImage? and put those on the scrollView so it can hand them off to the image view once it is ready. Could you please refresh my memory: Does viewDidLoad get called BEFORE or AFTER the segue? this will make things easier or harder.

Comment: If viewDidLoad happens first, you can then just make a public property of FriendProfileView rather than let  FriendProfileView. and then you just make some minor changes to the code i gave you and it will not crash

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
print(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row]) 
let dictData = ["name" : arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row], "image" :  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.row]]
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: dictData)
```

}

and in:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if(segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){
    let controller =  segue.destinationViewController as! MyViewController
let data = sender as NSDictionary
//Assign data to controller here you must create dicdata in destination controller
controller.data = data
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Write following `code` in `CollectionviewController class`.

Take `global object of NSDictionary`.

```
var dicSelected : NSDictionary!
```

Then Write following `code`

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if(segue.identifier == "PushNextViewController"){
            var nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! NextViewController
            nextViewOBJ.dicData = self.dicSelected;

        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.dicSelected = ["friendName" : arrFriends[indexPath.row], "FriendImage" :  arrFriends[indexPath.row]]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PushNextViewController", sender: nil)
    }
```

And in `nextController` need to take one `NSDictionary` as `global object` and your `code` looks like below.

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

     var dicData : NSDictionary!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(self.dicData);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Comment: It Still crashes http://puu.sh/kZbCw/c421390212.png, but the data is being added to nextViewOBJ

Comment: Please verify your `destination View controller` is `FriendProfile`. Your storyboard must be look like http://postimg.org/image/92k52soh9/

Comment: My destination Controller is FriendProfile, remember FriendProfile is embedded in a scrollview

Comment: `Compiler` is not able to find `FriendProfile` controller. Please check entire structure and and use `breakpoints` to check you are getting `nil` or `object of Controller`.

Comment: friendProfilePages is a scrollview where I place viewcontrollers in them. http://puu.sh/kZcHn/79cc3390de.png

Comment: @xxtmanxx you are going in wrong way, first send data to your scrollviewcontroller and then in `wilAppear` method set your Scrollview object.

Comment: For now just pass data to your `scrollview class` ex Friendprofilepages and then you need to setup `Friendprofile` their one by one in `for loop` or in `while loop`.

Comment: Yes one by one and set xPosition or yPosition which you want., and set dictionary for relevant controller.

Comment: Yes that is perfect,  May be now you are  not getting crash error.

Comment: I am close to resolving this, but it says dicData is nil.

Comment: @xxtmanxx you need to set your `NSDictionary` as i am just send you demo, how you can send data.

Comment: I get an error when I do it like this `var dicData : NSDictionary<String, UIImageView> = [:]` http://puu.sh/l0oCA/1adcce5964.png